# 'method' object is not subscriptable error appears when using get function

Tags: python, django, function, web, django-views

Django rises an error of ('method' object is not subscriptable) when trying to access username attribute from class User .
imports :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
```

the function that cause the error :

```
class UserPostListView(PostListView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 2
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username= self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by['-date']
```

I tried using square brackets instead of parentheses, but it raised a similar error .

Comment: If it's telling you that a method is not subscriptable, that means you're using square brackets where you should be using parentheses.  For example, perhaps `.order_by['-date']` should be `.order_by('-date')`.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank you so much! I saw this solution multiple times before but I didn't notice that I had order_by in square brackets.